# Compare Pandas dataframes and add column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframe as below

```
df1     df2 
A       A   C
A1      A1  C1
A2      A2  C2
A3      A3  C3
A1      A4  C4
A2          
A3          
A4
```

The values of column 'A' are defined in  df2 in column 'C'.
I want to add a new column to df1 with column B with its value from df2 column 'C'

The final df1 should look like this

```
df1
A   B
A1  C1
A2  C2
A3  C3
A1  C1
A2  C2
A3  C3
A4  C4
```

I can loop over df2 and add the value to df1 but its time consuming as the data is huge.

```
    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
           df1.loc[df1.A.isin([row['A']]), 'B']= row['C']
```

Can someone help me to understand how can I solve this without looping over df2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can just merge and rename the col

```
df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left').rename(columns={'C':'B'})

In [103]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A1','A2','A3','A1','A2','A3','A4']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A1','A2','A3','A4'], 'C':['C1','C2','C4','C4']})
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left').rename(columns={'C':'B'})
merged

Out[103]:
    A   B
0  A1  C1
1  A2  C2
2  A3  C4
3  A1  C1
4  A2  C2
5  A3  C4
6  A4  C4
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestion. I used this solution as it would merge other columns in df2 to df1. Thanks @EdChum

Comment: There is also semantic difference between `merge` and `map` in that if the lookup in df1 doesn't exist in df2 then `merge` will insert `NaN` whilst `map` will throw a `KeyError`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
df1['B'] = df1.A.map(df2.set_index('A')['C'])
print (df1)
    A   B
0  A1  C1
1  A2  C2
2  A3  C3
3  A1  C1
4  A2  C2
5  A3  C3
6  A4  C4
```

It is same as `map` by `dict`:

```
d = df2.set_index('A')['C'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'A4': 'C4', 'A3': 'C3', 'A2': 'C2', 'A1': 'C1'}

df1['B'] = df1.A.map(d)
print (df1)
    A   B
0  A1  C1
1  A2  C2
2  A3  C3
3  A1  C1
4  A2  C2
5  A3  C3
6  A4  C4
```

**Timings**:

`len(df1)=7`:

```
In [161]: %timeit merged = df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left').rename(columns={'C':'B'})
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 ms per loop

In [162]: %timeit df1['B'] = df1.A.map(df2.set_index('A')['C'])
The slowest run took 4.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 873 µs per loop
```

`len(df1)=70k`:

```
In [164]: %timeit merged = df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left').rename(columns={'C':'B'})
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop

In [165]: %timeit df1['B'] = df1.A.map(df2.set_index('A')['C'])
100 loops, best of 3: 6.05 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) method, here are three approaches with different indexing schemes -

```
df1['B'] = df2.C[df2.A.searchsorted(df1.A)].values
df1['B'] = df2.C[df2.A.searchsorted(df1.A)].reset_index(drop=True)
df1['B'] = df2.C.values[df2.A.searchsorted(df1.A)]
```