# Compare 2 dataframe and add difference column, Python 3.6

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with 10 columns

```
df1: col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
```

and another data frame with 5 columns

```
 df2: col1, col2, col6, col9, col3
```

I want to compare `df2` with `df1` and add columns of `df1` to `df2` which is not present.

This is not duplicate of [Compare Pandas dataframes and add column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608652/compare-pandas-dataframes-and-add-column), I dont want add any values from `df1`, just want to add columns with blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[5,6,7]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,7,7], 'c':[4,4,4], 'e':[0,0,0]})

>>> dfa
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
>>> dfb
   a  c  e
0  7  4  0
1  7  4  0
2  7  4  0
```

Find the column(s) that are different

```
>>> col_diff = dfb.columns.difference(dfa.columns)
>>> col_diff
Index(['c', 'e'], dtype='object')
```

Make a list of the new columns and add them:

```
>>> new = col_diff.tolist()
>>> new
['c', 'e']
>>> 
>>> for col in new:
...     dfa[col] = None

>>> dfa
   a  b     c     e
0  1  5  None  None
1  2  6  None  None
2  3  7  None  None
>>>
```

---

Using DataFrame.assign (same initial DataFrames)

```
>>> # try it when the df indices are different
>>> dfc = dfb.set_index('a')
>>> dfc
   c  e
a      
7  4  0
7  4  0
7  4  0

>>> diff = dfc.columns.difference(dfa.columns)
>>> new = diff.tolist()
>>> new = {col:None for col in new}
>>> dfa = dfa.assign(**new)

>>> dfa
   a  b     c     e
0  1  5  None  None
1  2  6  None  None
2  3  7  None  None
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to do this the indices must match up. Assuming they do, try something like:

```
pd.concat([df1.drop(df2.columns, axis=1), df2], axis=1)
```